# Problema com interação em loop FOR usando TStringList

Tags: delphi, for

Tenho um `TStringList` que armazena nomes de caminho absoluto de alguns arquivos e eu quero colocar esses nomes em um arquivo de texto somente se o nome atual verificado ainda não existir dentro de arquivo de texto.

Ao executar estes passos pela primeira vez, todo o conteúdo da lista de textos é gravado, mas quando é executado pela segunda vez, o segundo `FOR` não consegue verificar e escreve algumas linhas do `TStringList` que já foram gravado antes, e desta vez, com algumas repetições.

Qualquer sugestão aqui será bem-vinda.

Aqui é a minha última tentativa:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  ListPathFiles, ListStoredPathFiles: TStringList;
  StoreFile: TextFile;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function FileSize(const aFilename: String): Int64;
  var
    info: TWin32FileAttributeData;
  begin
    result := -1;

    if NOT GetFileAttributesEx(PWideChar(aFileName), GetFileExInfoStandard, @info) then
      EXIT;

    result := Int64(info.nFileSizeLow) or Int64(info.nFileSizeHigh shl 32);
  end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
I, J: Integer;
begin
  I:= 0;
  J:= 0;

if not FileExists('paths.txt') then begin
      AssignFile(StoreFile, 'paths.txt');
      Rewrite(StoreFile);
      CloseFile(StoreFile);
end;

ListPathFiles:= TStringList.Create;
ListStoredPathFiles:= TStringList.Create;

if FileSize('paths.txt') = 0 then
 begin
    ListStoredPathFiles.Add('');
 end;

ListPathFiles.Add('C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\test\File1.txt');
ListPathFiles.Add('C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\test\File2.txt');
ListPathFiles.Add('C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\test\File3.txt');
ListPathFiles.Add('C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\test\File4.txt');
ListPathFiles.Add('C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\test\File5.txt');

ListStoredPathFiles.LoadFromFile('paths.txt');

     for I := 0 to ListPathFiles.Count-1 do
      begin

      for J := 0 to ListStoredPathFiles.Count-1 do
       begin
        if Pos(ListPathFiles.Strings[I], ListStoredPathFiles.Strings[J]) > 0  then

        begin
          Break;
        end

        else
         begin

             AssignFile(StoreFile, 'paths.txt');
             Append(StoreFile);
             Writeln(StoreFile, ListPathFiles.Strings[I]);
             CloseFile(StoreFile);

            ShowMessage('New path added in text file!');

          end;

      end;

    end;

    ListPathFiles.Free;
    ListStoredPathFiles.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teste desta maneira:

```
for i := 0 to Pred(ListPathFiles.Count) do
begin
  if Pos(ListPathFiles.Strings[i], ListStoredPathFiles.Text) < 0  then
  begin
    AssignFile(StoreFile, 'paths.txt');
    Append(StoreFile);
    Writeln(StoreFile, ListPathFiles.Strings[i]);
    CloseFile(StoreFile);

    ShowMessage('New path added in text file!');  
  end;
end;
```

O que estamos tentando agora é verificar se NÃO existe o texto da Strings[i] em todo texto da lista **ListStoredPathFiles**.

Observe que o código foi otimizado e resumido! Tente sempre não usar `Breaks` ou múltiplas estruturas de repetição! Assim seu código fica mais limpo e organizado.

Comment: Valeu mesmo kra! só mais uma coisinha, o correto seria `= 0` e não `<  0` como você colocou, pois a função `Pos` não retorna valores menores que 0 :-). Após essa alteração, sua lógica funcionou corretamnte como esperado! Muito obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: rsrsrs Mania, o correto ali seria < 1, pois, se trata de um inteiro o retorno, o ideal é que funcionou!